# How to restrict 10 rows to dispaly in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I wrote a SQL Server query to display rownumbers and total rows to the table .

Up to this it is working fine

ex:

```
select 
    row_number() over (order by  partyid) as Rownumbers,
    count(*) over() totalrows,
    partyname 
from party
```

Now I need to display only 10 rows, if I am trying to restrict 10 rows per table then it is throwing the error like invalid column name rownumbers

ex:

```
select 
   row_number() over (order by  partyid) as Rownumbers,
   count(*) over() totalrows,
   partyname 
from party
where Rownumbers between 1 and 5
```

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Invalid column name 'Rownumbers'.

How do I fix it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You don't have a `partition by` clause in the `row_number()`.  I think yo can do what you want using `top`:

```
 select top 10 row_number() over (order by partyid) as Rownumbers,
        count(*) over() as totalrows, partyname 
 from party
 order by partyid
```

Comment: hi Gordon , thank you for your reply . the above functionality will not useful every time because i can display only 10 records suppose if i want to export 10k records to excel  but i need to display only 10 records per page then logic will fail

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a subquery:

```
select *
from (
    select 
         row_number() over (order by partyid) as Rownumbers,
         count(*) over() totalrows,
         partyname 
    from party 
) t
where Rownumbers between 1 and 5
```